# How to make a bounded map of queue in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, queue

I need to make a dictionary of bounded queues. The following is what I have so far.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import deque

d = defaultdict(deque)
...
q = d[name]
```

To make a bounded queue: `q = deque(maxlen = 10)` works but I'm not sure how to do this when the queue is in a dictionary. Can anyone help me make a map of bounded queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean

```
from functools import partial

d = defaultdict(partial(deque, maxlen=10))
```

?

Comment: @soulcheck: I find `partial` prettier.

Comment: it does the same thing though, being more explicit about it but also a bit longer

Comment: Are there concerns about thread safety with this approach? For instance, if two threads simultaneously try to access `d['one']` when `'one'` is not yet in `d`, what will happen - could they possibly be working off different instantiations of `deque` or are they guaranteed to get the same one?